# Problem when disassembling 16-bit binary one instruction at the time

Tags: reverse-engineering, assembly

I am currently disassembling a binary that enters vm86 mode, so 32-bit binary in 16-bit mode. While IDA fails to do that correctly, I took the initiative to do it by myself.

Problem is, I very often stumble on two "0x00" opcodes that follow each other, and that wouldn't make any good instruction.
So here, I have the possibility to take the second zero and the following opcode, creating strange instructions, but that may work, or skip the two zeroes everytime (cf screenshot)

My question is, **what is the correct way of disassembling here ?** So that I don't make any bad instructions that would destruct my instructions flow

Here is an example (I tried to do something clear enough):

[image: Disassemlber]

Comment: Could this just be constant data embedded in the code segment?  Is there any control flow that causes this range to be executed?